# How can I explicitly use the default viewport setting of the client in HTML?

Tags: html, mobile

My mobile webapp uses this viewport meta:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

On some minor pages I need to explicitly change this setting (I can't drop it altogether) to be "use the default client setting, as if there is no "viewport" set by the app".

What is the HTML for this? please note: I don't need to *change* this via jQuery. I just need the right HTML for the header.

Thanks!

Comment: To rely on  client settings, don't you just need to remove yours? i.e. remove your device `<meta>` tag from the header of those pages?

Comment: Yes, but, as I wrote: I can't drop it altogether.

Comment: Sorry, i thought you meant you couldn't remove it from all pages. In that case, is there any way you can manipulate the HTML of your target  pages? Possibly just remove the 'content' attribute?

Comment: Nope. I need to write it "right" on the server, before it reaches the client. No edit after that.

Comment: I'd try using **[server-side agent detection](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/09/24/server-side-device-detection-history-benefits-how-to/)**, to serve up the desired code before it reaches the client device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easier than I thought:

`<meta name="viewport" content="">`

Thanks to @Timmah for his hint!